# UITableView reloadData() from ViewController with extension of UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I worked my table view with an extension to the ViewController.

How can I use reloadData() as in TableViewController?

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return articles.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let a = articles[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "articleCell", for: indexPath) as! ArticleTableViewCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = a.title

        return cell
    }  
}
```

Comment: Add an outlet for the table view and reload as you please

Comment: Where do you want to call `reloadData`?

Comment: you need to read a tutorial on how to use `UITableView` in `Swift`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, wherefrom data coming into articles array if data is static meaning you defining in your code then you simply create an outlet for tableView and use    `self.tableView.reloadData` in viewDidLoad
and if your data is coming from api then you can use this code

```
     ` DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableview.reloadData()
        }`
```

after you parsing your data into data

Comment: Some how I didn't think about the outlet ;) ,  thank you, the rest with the GCD I know, Thank you